# jQuery append duplicating elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following JavaScript:

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
    return s
        ? this.before(s).remove()
        : jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
};

$(function() {
    var parentContainer = $("<ul><ul>");
    var textContainer =  $("<li></li>");
    var textInput = $("<textarea rows=10 cols=10></textarea>");
    textContainer.append(textInput);
    parentContainer.append(textContainer);

    alert(parentContainer.outerHTML());
});
```

the alert will display the following code:

```
<ul><ul></ul><li><textarea rows="10" cols="10"></textarea></li></ul>
```

from what I understand it is nesting the `li` element into the first `ul` element but it includes a copy of the first wrapper `<ul></ul>`.

does anyone understand why does this happen?

Comment: you have a typo on line `var parentContainer = $("<ul><ul>");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of  `$("<ul><ul>")`, you are creating 2 `ul` elements. Change it to:

```
var parentContainer = $("<ul></ul>");
```

Or:

```
var parentContainer = $("<ul/>");
```

Comment: Thank allot for the answer, I guess things like this happens when you'r tired.

Comment: @BenjaminAlbert You are welcome, yeah, tiredness is a recipe of pain in programming :)